# How to require theme's file in the plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing a plugin, and trying `require` a PHP file from my theme in my plugin.
Now, this code works:

```
require('/home/starter/public_html/wp-content/themes/starter/inc/more_posts.php');
```

But I want the plugin retrieve the theme's dir path automatically, so that the only thing I need to add is `/inc/more_posts.php`, same as `plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )` function does for the plugin. Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: Use `get_stylesheet_directory():` file path to current Theme directory.

Comment: That does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use,

```
get_stylesheet_directory();
```

It retrieves stylesheet directory Path for the current theme/child theme.

For more info : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory